# Encrypt/Hash database Ids before sending to client side

Tags: java, encryption, hash

I have a requirement that lists of some objects to be displayed in the client side using table. And the user may edit or delete any of those objects. For that purpose I am using hidden database ids in the client side. But I think this is not appropriate if the user can guess the ids. Hence, what can be done to improve this mechanism? What should be the encryption/hash algorithm for this purpose?

Comment: What can the client do if it guesses the ID?

Comment: The client may manipulate other user's data as all the data of all the users is stored in single table.

Comment: So your server doesn't check whether the user is actually allowed to manipulate that data before it manipulates the data?

Comment: Server checks the validity and the business logic allows sometimes to manipulate other's data.

Comment: The server should check whether the data belongs to the user manipulating it, then this won't be a problem.

Comment: But still I don't want to show them the real ids.

Comment: If you fix it so that users can't mess with each others' data just by knowing the IDs, then it doesn't matter if the users can see the IDs.

Comment: Yeah you are right. But still I would like to know the answer for my queries.